# How can I create a javascript ServiceWorker instance from a string?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

The following script in my index.html file:

```
<script>
    const serviceWorkerCode = `
          self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
            console.log('Fetch intercepted!', event.request.url);
            event.respondWith(fetch(event.request));
          });
    `;
    const blob = new Blob([serviceWorkerCode], { type: 'application/javascript' });
    const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    navigator.serviceWorker.register(blobUrl)
        .then(registration => {
            console.log('Service Worker registered!');
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Service Worker registration failed:', error);
        });
    URL.revokeObjectURL(blobUrl);
</script>
```

results in

> (index):43 Service Worker registration failed: TypeError: Failed to
> register a ServiceWorker: The URL protocol of the script
> ('blob:https://localhost:7128/e50c29d9-330b-41c9-8f5d-615f16120ea6')
> is not supported.

I suspect it's because the blob protocol doesn't work with ServiceWorker.register function, so I'm hoping someone knows how I can activate a ServiceWorker instance based on a string of javascript.

The overarching objective is to create a single html file that contains all of a website's files as embedded streams and the ServiceWorker serves up those streams when fetched.  If someone has solved this in another way, that would also be a great answer.

Comment: Also, [the MIME Type for JS is `text/javascript`, not `application/javascript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types#textjavascript)

Comment: FWIW, [the current specification for Service Workers **requires** the Service Worker's `scriptURL` to have either `http:` or `https:` URI schemes and if not to throw a `TypeError`](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#start-register),  so using `blob:` or `data:` won't work.

Comment: I have tried text/javascript as well.  Also, I understand that the ServiceWorker is limited to http(s) or localhost, but I'm hoping someone has solved the idea of serving files dynamically, despite this lack of feature in ServiceWorker (presumably because of security concerns)

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR: You can't.

---

- [The current specification for Service Workers requires the Service Worker's scriptURL to have either `http:` or `https:` URI schemes and if not to throw a `TypeError`](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#start-register).

  - So using `blob:` or `data:` URI schemes won't work.
  - Source:

    > - If `scriptURL`’s scheme is not one of "`http`" and "`https`", reject promise with a `TypeError` and abort these steps.
    > - If `scopeURL`’s scheme is not one of "`http`" and "`https`", reject promise with a `TypeError` and abort these steps.
- [Back in 2014, the original designers of Service Workers rejected a request to allow for Blob/String script sources, citing security concerns](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/578):

  > [annevk commented on Dec 8, 2014](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/578#issuecomment-66066294)
  > We don't want to support this because it would mean a single successful attack on a server could compromise users for a long time.
  > [...]
  > If it allows a SW to be registered in a way that prevents the owner of the controlled origin from unregistering it, we don't want it

  > [mkruisselbrink commented on Aug 26, 2016](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/578#issuecomment-242835789)
  > The problem is that to unregister you need to first actually get to get code to run on that origin. If the service worker doesn't have an actual network url to check for updates, the service worker can just intercept all navigation, and never let any new request to the server actually reach the server, so even fixing the server won't enable fixing the clients. Basically the entire 24 hour update check wouldn't be possible anymore with blob urls.

Comment: So is there a way to achieve stream-based websites by any method?

Comment: @Sean What do you mean by "Stream-based website"?

Comment: Using my original post's code as an example, instead of simply logging the URL's to the console, I would instead return a string representing the requested file.  That string would be sourced from the index.html.

Comment: An alternative approach would be to use `data:` URIs where-appropriate (e.g. small SVGs, things under ~2KB), and anything else could be stored (and compressed) inside a `<script>` (with a custom `type=""`) and a script on DOMContentLoaded would read/decompress those resources into `blob:` URIs and replace all references (e.g. in <img src="">`, etc) accordingly.

Comment: I don't have control over the URI's.  I'm using Blazor and want to move all their DLLs and other files into the index.html so it's a single-file app

Comment: @Sean If you're using Blazor then this whole thing is kinda moot, no?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252792/discussion-between-sean-and-dai).